# beginner: python or django is_new

Tags: python, django

diclaimer: I am new to python but have experience programming in Drupal

I'm following the tutorial here (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08/) where the authors write the following

```
def foo_view(request):
    m_list = MyModel.objects.filter(is_new=True)
    return render_to_response('template1.html', {'m_list': m_list})
```

I searched that online book (no explanation given), the printed python .096 version of the book (no explanation given), and randomly searched through Google (light references to session), but I'm still unsure what is_new means, especially in this context.

Thoughts?

Comment: Gotta love the irony of getting tripped up on something called `is_new` because you're new ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_new is a field in the model